# Error when retrieving data from database (ado.net)

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm getting an error when retrieving data from the child row. Basically I need the `lecturerName` from `tbl_lecturer`, `projectTitle` from `tbl_lecturer_project`.

Here is my code.

```
//get data from 3 tables
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // .xsd file name
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Connection string replace 'databaseservername' with your db server name
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataAdapter adapter;

con.Open();

//Stored procedure calling. It is already in sample db.
string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_allocated_project where allocatedGroupId='" + team + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
ds = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl_allocated_project");

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lecturer_project";
adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl_lecturer_project");

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_lecturer";
adapter.Fill(ds, "tbl_lecturer");

DataRelation dr1 = new DataRelation("dr1", ds.Tables["tbl_lecturer"].Columns["lecturerId"],ds.Tables["tbl_lecturer_project"].Columns["lecturerId"]);
DataRelation dr2 = new DataRelation("dr2", ds.Tables["tbl_lecturer_project"].Columns["lecturerProjectId"], ds.Tables["tbl_allocated_project"].Columns["allocatedProjectId"]);
ds.Relations.Add(dr1);
ds.Relations.Add(dr2);

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["tbl_allocated_project"].Rows)
{
    lblDisplay.Text = "";
    //lblDisplay.Text += row["allocatedGroupId"];
    //lblDisplay.Text += " " + row["intro"];

    foreach (DataRow col in row.GetChildRows(dr2))
    {
        DataRow rowdata = col.GetParentRows(dr1)[0];
        //lblDisplay.Text += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        lblDisplay.Text += rowdata["projectTitle"];
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> *GetChildRows requires a row whose table is `tbl_lecturer_project`, but the specified row's table is `tbl_allocated_project`.*

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Should this:

```
DataRelation dr2 = new DataRelation("dr2", ds.Tables["tbl_lecturer_project"].Columns["lecturerProjectId"], ds.Tables["tbl_allocated_project"].Columns["allocatedProjectId"]);
```

be this:

```
DataRelation dr2 = new DataRelation("dr2", ds.Tables["tbl_allocated_project"].Columns["lecturerProjectId"], ds.Tables["tbl_lecturer_project"].Columns["allocatedProjectId"]);
```

This would make `tbl_allocated_project` the parent of `tbl_lecturer_project`, which should allow you to call `GetChildRows` on it.